# How can I open up VLC via command line (http) with the playlist paused by default?

Tags: http, streaming, vlc-media-player

I am using the following command to open up the stream with an audio cd in the playlist:

**vlc -I http cdda://**

When run, it automatically starts playing.  I need VLC to open up, populate the playlist, but not start playing until explicitly told to.  I heard there was an easy way to do this in older versions of VLC, but not anymore?  Can anyone help me or confirm this?

Comment: Voting to migrate to Super User. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 6):

Try `vlc --no-playlist-autostart`